# Is it possible to use a value from a different database in rules (Firebase Realtime database)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So i'm storing my data using email address as a parent (replacing non valid characters with numbers)

so my question(s) is , is it possible to :

1. Only accept write operations from users with that email value (i guess it is possible using root.child...val )
2. i have multiple Realtime databases , is it possible to get a value from another database, or should i just duplicate data accross all databases where needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database's server-side security rules can only access data in the same database. There is no way to access data in another database from within the rules, so you will have to ensure that all data the rules need to access is present in the same database.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the quick answer.
I guess i'll just do that, it's only a single value anyway so it's not a big deal.

Comment: Ah sorry, i don't have enough reputation to upvote yet